# Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5983 Turns Back On After Shutdown When Plugged In

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, shutdown, toshiba-laptop

I have a **Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5983** running *Windows 10*, originally *Windows 7*. Whenever I leave it plugged in while I shut it down, it boots right back up. If I have it unplugged when it is shutting down, it doesn't. I am not telling it to boot back up after I shut it down, it does it on its own. It has done this for years (even while running *Windows 7*), but only recently have I decided to figure out what could be wrong. Based on the information I have given, any ideas what the problem is? If more information is needed, let me know and I will supply to the best of my ability.

I have tried searching on Google to see if anyone else has the same issue. So far, I have found one instance, but the solutions are either not applicable to my laptop or don't fix it. One solution said that there was a Trojan on their PC, so I am currently running a Full System Scan with Bitdefender. While I wait for any answer or comment here, I will continue searching for any other solutions.

Comment: The Bitdefender full system scan returned clean. I may try Windows Defender, but am doubting it will expose anything.